# npm install issue with laravel

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm

please i need you help me ,i am learning laravel according to the steps in the documentation ,but every time i run `npm install` command ,it does not work and i got this error

[image]

> PS C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-authentication> npm install
> npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-08-12T19_52_24_666Z-debug-0.log

Comment: We need more info. What version of NPM? I also recommend using Laragon instead of XAMPP as it comes with a recent version of Node built in.

Comment: **npm version 8.16.0**

Comment: i also tried with the latest version of laragon but it still don't work, i downloaded the full version of laragon that have the integrated npm and nodejs

Answer (score 0):

`cd application` first, and then `npm install`

Comment: i'm already in the application folder `laravel-authentication`